# Changing a defined constant in a dll compilated file from external application

Tags: c++, gauss

Please, help me to figure out this. I have the following code in C (example):

```
#define cutoff 22;
double age;

if (age == cutoff) {
  cout << "Good morning.";
} else {
  cout << "Good evening.";
}
```

This code is built as a .dll file and taken from a Gauss programming language code.
I wish to change #define cutoff 22, let say, to:

#define cutoff 50
#define cutoff 51
.... etc

from the Gauss code and that the dll file can incorporate these new values into the remaining code above in the defined variable "cutoff".

How can I do that? Is there another more efficient way?

Thank you!

Comment: The code is not C and I am not sure how/whether the `gauss` tag is relevant.

Comment: If you want to change the macro's value you need to rebuild the dll (and any other components using it).

Comment: Also `cutoff` is not a variable. It is a text replacement preprocessor macro.